# What does this 4 line java code means in android application?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-windowmanager

In my java application i have this code

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
  {
  this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
  super.onAttachedToWindow();
  }
```

when i build it for **android 2.3 (level 10)**  it compiles and works fine. But when i build it for **android 4.0 (level 15)** it compiles and gives me crash at run time and following error

```
07-16 14:00:03.090: E/AndroidRuntime(29487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 14:00:03.090: E/AndroidRuntime(29487): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.
```

when i comment this line and build it works fine and no issue..

```
//this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
```

so i am not getting why this happning and whats this code means?

**Edit :**
some reference are here

[when I run app on my phone.The version is android 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498938/when-i-run-app-on-my-phone-the-version-is-android-4-0-3#comment16888792_11498938)

[toddler safe app on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072866/toddler-safe-app-on-android#comment16888776_8072866)

Comment: It simply means when your activity comes to foreground like onDisplay in blackberry

Comment: Simply set targetSDK to less then 14 . Then it will work http://stackoverflow.com/a/32587231/3496570

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
  {
  this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
  super.onAttachedToWindow();
  }
```

is used to **disable home button in android** but

this **security flaw has been fixed in newer versions of Android** so it will not work in ICS and jelly bean...!!

Comment: It's giving me the error that java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type cannot be changed after the window is added.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this issue putting

```
this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
```

in onCreate before calling super.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Saludos desde Medellín

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override    
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);    
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

I had some problems with windowAttached as well, try using windowFocusChanged instead.