# How do i disable both the home button and notification bar in android

Tags: android, locking, android-notification-bar, home-button

I am making a custom lock app and for that i need to disable the home button and notification bar so that the messages cannot be read/ apps cannot be accessed from the notification bar before the phone is unlocked.

I have disabled the home button using the following code:

```
@Override
      public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, android.view.KeyEvent event) {

            if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)){

                  return true;
            }
            return false;
      }

      public void onAttachedToWindow()// to disable Home button 
      {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

          super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }
```

Comment: You will not be able to disable home button in android ICS and above ..Google does not allow home button disabling in the ics and above.I was myself creating a custom locker and had to drop the idea because of this issue I faced in ics and other versions.There no way to disable home button in these versions!

Comment: but is it possible to disable both the home button and notification bar in 2.2 and above?

Comment: yes you can disable home button below ics .

Comment: both the home button and notification bar??

Answer (score 1):

try this to disable to notification bar

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: this seems to work on the emulator but does disable the notification bar when the app is used on the phone

Comment: try commenting out your onAttachedToWindow override and see if that helps

Comment: ok, try just removing this then from setType `|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`

Comment: still doesnt work..
all these work only when home key is enabled..
what i want to do is disable both the home key and the notification bar simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

For your reference please look at [Disable Home Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560180/what-does-this-4-line-java-code-means-in-android-application). And for hiding notification bar in android, you can use in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```