# Android Crash, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I uploaded an Android Application to the market, and, for some reason a user is getting this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1331)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout(IWindowSession.java:664)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3594)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1193)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2450)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4444)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am pretty sure I never use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG` as referenced in other postings.  I do however, have a window that switches between `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE` and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`.  Which seems like it could be the error.  I would prefer not changing this as it would require me to have two windows instead of just one.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

check `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-sdk  //************
            android:targetSdkVersion="X"/>
```

X must be less than 14 Or remove this attribute.
good luck guy.

Comment: How did you know that ?

Comment: Albert Qing this isn't the solution.how to make it work for latest API

Comment: Many conditions may cause this problem, this just a choice, not absolute!