# Showing a TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT (Window type can not be changed after the window is added.)

Tags: java, android

I want to show an alert window to ask a question to user. I am using the code given below. I get the following error:

> Window type can not be changed after the window is added.

```
try {
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_subscription_buy, null);
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    wm.addView(mTopView, params);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I fix it or is there any solution to ask a question to user on top of all activities?

Note: I granted user with this Manifest permission rule:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Enes, possibly [this is the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19314516/4978534)

Comment: This is not solved my problem, I think this is not about that.

Comment: I've tested your code is working in android 7.0. It runs without exception. Which version gives this exception?

Comment: The code is running perfectly. But I am using a SDK for image editing and it requires this manifest attribute.