# Android - Error - IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

I am debugging an android app (which was unfortunately written by someone else). The app has a splash activity which lasts for 1 second and then the transitions to a landing page activity using an intent. The app was running fine until I noticed that the targetSDKVersion was not set in the manifest file. I set it to 18. And then when I run the app in the emulator, the app crashes and I see the following error in logcat:

```
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1435)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout(IWindowSession.java:835)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:5034)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1399)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-24 06:14:26.840: E/AndroidRuntime(2457):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The app crashes immediately after showing the splash screen and before the landing page activity is loaded. The following blocks show relevant code blocks from the splash activity.

### Splash Activity

```
private Thread mSplashThread;    
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    final SplashScreenActivity sPlashScreen = this;   
        mSplashThread =  new Thread(){

@Override
        public void run(){
        try {
            synchronized(this){
                // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                wait(1000);
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
        }

        finish();

        // Run next activity
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, LandingPageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);                 
        }
    };
    mSplashThread.start();        
    }

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt)
{
    if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
    try{
        synchronized(mSplashThread){
            mSplashThread.notifyAll();
            }
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        Log.v("This is it", e.getCause().getMessage());
    }
}
return true;
}
```

Now in all my research to debug this issue I found suggestions to check for following code piece but I don't have anything like this in my app:

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow()
    {  
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
        super.onAttachedToWindow();  
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this code?

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem but you should call `finish();` after `startActivity()`.

Comment: @codeMagic - I tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: @nurisezgin - The splash activity just shows the company banner (logo) and takes the user to a landing page.

Comment: Simply set targetSDK to less then 14 . Then it will work http://stackoverflow.com/a/32587231/3496570

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is resolved. There was indeed an occurrence of "onAttachedToWindow" in one of the empty base classes. It worked after removing that override. As I mentioned in my original post, I had come across this solution in another post. Here is a reference to that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072866/toddler-safe-app-on-android).

In my case however this code wasn't in any of the user-facing activities. It was in a blank parent activity which my landing page was inheriting. Hope someone saves a few hours after this post.

Comment: +1 I have encountered this error just now when trying to add Android 4.4 KitKat support. I have to comment out my overriding `onAttachedToWindow` method in one of my Activities in order for everything to work nicely. Thank you, Surya.

Answer (score 3):

I have an solution for you.
It is not really useful but can resolve your problem.
 You should change your minsdk version to 8.

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />`

Let try it and tell me the result ;)

Comment: That was the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use delay try this;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    private Thread mSplashThread;    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        View root = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        root.setOnClickListener(this);
        final SplashScreenActivity sPlashScreen = this;   
        mSplashThread =  new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finish();

                // Run next activity
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, LandingPageActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);                 
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSplashThread.start();
    }

}
```