# Child mode for keeping my android app open?

Tags: java, android

I need to know how to keep the user (child in this case) from accidentally hitting the home button and others closing the app. I want a parent to be able to hand the baby the phone and as she/he taps it will make sounds. That's all. My little one is my beta tester and she keeps closing it unintentionally then getting mad. I'm using android studio with ics+ support.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible by overriding the `onPause()` method, or relaunching the app when closed, both shown [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652238/preventing-the-home-button-to-close-activity)

I would recommend checking if the phone is running 5.0 or higher. If it is, then show how to use [screen pinning](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/17/lollipop-feature-spotlight-screen-pinning-allows-you-to-lock-your-device-to-a-single-app-before-handing-it-to-a-friend/), which requires the overview and back buttons to be held together for 5 seconds - something which a small child is unlikely to do.

Comment: Ill look into that thank you. I have no problem with bumping up the support I offer. Screen pinning is users choice right? I could call a dialog to ask if they would like to activate that before using app then I assume?

Comment: Yes, screen pinning is something the user must do. I would recommend launching the settings page with the applicable option, and demonstrating how to activate screen pinning in the app itself.   
EDIT: It seems that this is not the case: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204829/screen-pinning-3rd-party-apps-programmatically  

https://datatheorem.github.io/android/2014/12/29/android-screen-pinning/  

https://github.com/darryncampbell/LockTaskMode-Exerciser